integral equation arising from probability
I want to find a distribution on the positive reals such that $2X$ is distributed as $X*(1+\frac 1 {2Y})$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables distributed according to that distribution. (The context comes from https://doi.org/10.1214/aop/1029867128, Proposition 2.8.)
Is there a solution to the equation
$$ f(x) = \int \frac{4t}{2t+1} f\left(\frac{4t}{2t+1} x\right) f(t) \, dt$$
where $f$ is a density function on the positive reals?
I'm looking for any solutions other than full mass at $1/2$.

The only solution is full mass at $1/2$.

Lemma: if $U$ and $V$ are independent, and $U$ and $U+V$ have the same distribution, then $V=0$ with probability $1$.
Proof: Consider characteristic functions. We have $\phi_{U}(t)\phi_V(t)=\phi_{U+V}(t)=\phi_U(t)$. But $\phi_U(t)$ is non-zero on an interval around the origin (because $\phi_U(0)=1$ and $\phi_U$ is continuous), so $\phi_V(t)=1$ on an interval around the origin.
However, whenever $\phi_V(t)=1$ on any interval with non-empty interior (in fact, whenever $\phi_V(t_1)=\phi_V(t_2)=1$ for any non-zero $t_1$, $t_2$ which are not rational multiples of each other), it must be that $V=0$ with probability $1$. This is because if $t\neq 0$, then $\phi_V(t)=1$ implies that $V$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi/t$ with probability $1$.

Now for your example, you would have that $\log X$ has the same distribution as $\log X+\log\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4Y}\right)$. By the lemma above, you get that $\log\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4Y}\right)=0$ with probability $1$, i.e. $P(Y=1/2)=1$.

Or another, maybe simpler, way to finish the proof of the lemma: if $\phi_V(t)=1$ on an interval around the origin, then $\phi'_V(0)=\phi''_V(0)$, which implies that $V$ has mean and variance $0$.
